# How to deactivate some symfony2 debug toolbar elements?

Tags: symfony, profiler

I am using symfony2 and its debug toolbar is great.

However, I've come to install som extra bundles which add some elements and it is now displayed on two levels.

How can I do to remove some elements from the toolbar ?

For example, I don't need info about my phpversion, not about the route, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Elements of the toolbar are called `DataCollectors`, they are special services tagged with `data_collector`. In the following lines, i will take the `Time Datacollector` as example.

So in order to deactivate one of them, you first have to get his service id.
You can list all the `DataCollectors` by running the console command:

```
php console container:debug --show-private --tag='data_collector'
```

**The output is:**

```
[container] Public and private services with tag data_collector
Service ID                                                            template                                                          id                                    priority Class name
9d48641ce55174a7d8ab08e99157426bc290884423a78a5821440d644f6a37df_5    @WebProfiler/Collector/time.html.twig                             time                                  300      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\TimeDataCollector
```

So now you got the id of the service which is `time`, you have to build the name. Add `data_collector.` as a prefix of the id to get the name. The name of the service is `data_collector.time`.

Now as you want to deactivate it, you have to give it a Zero priority.

In your config.yml:

```
services:
    data_collector.time:
        class: "%data_collector.time.class%"
        tags:
           - {name: 'data_collector', priority: '0'}
```

Now the profiler doesn't have the `time` no more.

**This is a way to unable some profiler items properly**. ( A.K.A: A symfony update won't affect it, unless they change the name of the DataCollectors )

---

**The shortiest way** is to direcly put the zero priority in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/collectors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>
        <parameter key="data_collector.config.class">Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\ConfigDataCollector</parameter>
        <parameter key="data_collector.request.class">Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector</parameter>
        <parameter key="data_collector.exception.class">Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\ExceptionDataCollector</parameter>
        <parameter key="data_collector.events.class">Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\EventDataCollector</parameter>
        <parameter key="data_collector.logger.class">Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\LoggerDataCollector</parameter>
        <parameter key="data_collector.time.class">Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\TimeDataCollector</parameter>
        <parameter key="data_collector.memory.class">Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\MemoryDataCollector</parameter>
        <parameter key="data_collector.router.class">Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector</parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
[...]
        <service id="data_collector.time" class="%data_collector.time.class%" public="false">
            <tag name="data_collector" template="@WebProfiler/Collector/time.html.twig" id="time" priority="0" />
            <argument type="service" id="kernel" on-invalid="ignore" />
            <argument type="service" id="debug.stopwatch" on-invalid="ignore" />
        </service>
[..]
    </services>
</container>
```

All the DataCollectors are not defined in the same file. But here is a quick list of some of them:

```
data_collector.config:     
data_collector.request:
data_collector.router:
data_collector.security:
data_collector.logger:
data_collector.memory:
data_collector.exception:
data_collector.events:
swiftmailer.data_collector:
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with php-cache. It had CacheDataCollector which could crash symfony2 in some cases - https://github.com/php-cache/issues/issues/112
I tried solution above (with **priority 0**) - and it **doesnt worked**, data-collector still crashed symfony2

I dont have any ideas why priority = 0 should disable anything. 
You could check symfony2 ProfilerPass yourself, which process tag data_collector in
https://github.com/avorobiev/symfony2/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ProfilerPass.php

So, I have used pretty dirty patch intead - in application config I add service with the same name, but without tag data_collector.
Like

```
services:
  cache.data_collector:
    class: Cache\CacheBundle\DataCollector\CacheDataCollector
```

More clean and more stable way would be adding CompilerPass, which will remove tag - https://blog.liplex.de/disable-elements-in-the-symfony-developer-toolbar-with-compilerpass/