# Disable elements in Symfony toolbar

Tags: symfony, service, toolbar

There are a lot of elements in the Symfony toolbar. I don't need all of them. I already found out that they are called `data_collector` services. With setting the priority to `0` it's possible to [deactivate the time component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367619/how-to-deactivate-some-symfony2-debug-toolbar-elements), but it doesn't seem to work for the translation component.

Is there a single way to disable or remove the services individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I just missed to add the additional arguments necessary for the other `data_collector` services. Here how it looks like for other services I don't need at the time:

```
services:

    data_collector.translation:
        class: 'Symfony\Component\Translation\DataCollector\TranslationDataCollector'
        tags:
           - {name: 'data_collector', priority: '0'}
        arguments: [@translator.data_collector]

    data_collector.form:
        class: "%data_collector.form.class%"
        tags:
           - {name: 'data_collector', priority: '0'}
        arguments: [@data_collector.form.extractor]

    data_collector.logger:
        class: "%data_collector.logger.class%"
        tags:
           - {name: 'data_collector', priority: '0'}
        arguments: [@logger]

    data_collector.ajax:
        class: 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\AjaxDataCollector'
        tags:
           - {name: 'data_collector', priority: '0'}

    data_collector.twig:
        class: 'Symfony\Bridge\Twig\DataCollector\TwigDataCollector'
        tags:
           - {name: 'data_collector', priority: '0'}
        arguments: [@twig.profile]
```