# Override a symfony service tag with a compiler pass

Tags: symfony, service, tags

I'm trying to override a tag in a symfony service definition with a compiler pass. The service as an example would be `data_collector.translation`.

The goal is to deactivate the data collector service to disable the element in the symfony web developer toolbar. To do this, I have to set the `priority` of the `data_collector` tag to `0`.

I could also override it in my own service definition:

```
services:

    data_collector.translation:
        class: 'Symfony\Component\Translation\DataCollector\TranslationDataCollector'
        tags:
           - {name: 'data_collector', priority: '0'}
        arguments: [@translator.data_collector]
```

But as I want to do this for a few of the data collectors, I would need to know the mandatory arguments for the data collector definition. The priority works the same for all collectors and therefore I would only need the name of the collector to disable it.

So I wrote the following compiler pass:

```
class DataCollectorCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition('data_collector.translation')) {
            return;
        }
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('data_collector.translation');

        $tags = $definition->getTags();

        $tags['data_collector'][0]['priority'] = 0;

        $definition->setTags($tags);

        $container->setDefinition('data_collector.translation', $definition);
    }
}
```

To make things more wired: When I run this command:

```
$ php app/console container:debug --show-private --tag='data_collector'
```

I get the following output:

```
data_collector.translation @WebProfiler/Collector/translation.html.twig translation 0 Symfony\Component\Translation\DataCollector\TranslationDataCollector
```

So the priority even in the debugger is set to `0`.

But for which reason ever the element is still shown in the toolbar.

What did I do wrong here? Is there another mechanism for overwriting a tag within a compiler pass?

*The compiler pass does run (tested it with printing out stuff)*
*I'm using Symfony 2.7.1*

Comment: which version of symfony2 are you using?

Comment: Symfony 2.7.1 (added to description)

Comment: have you already see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367619/how-to-deactivate-some-symfony2-debug-toolbar-elements ?

Comment: @Matteo Yes, that's where I got the idea to do it with the services.yml and that is working, but I'd like to do it with a compiler pass

Comment: @gvf Yes it does. See the last cursive comments in the post ; ) Also the priority is set to `0` in the `container:debug`

Comment: @gvf But you said it worked for you? Because I tried it with `data_collector.form` and it also doesn't work there. What Symfony version do you use and how did you initialize the compiler pass? And where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the code does work, the only problem is, that the CompilerPass is run after the ProfilerPass which is part of the `FrameworkBundle`. Putting my bundle with the CompilerPass before the `FrameworkBundle` in the `AppKernel` solves the problem (more [information here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15256#issuecomment-121037457)). For not even initiating the data collectors it's better to remove all tags instead of just setting the priority to `0`.

That's what the final solution looks like:

```
class DataCollectorCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $collectorsToRemove = [
            'data_collector.form',
            'data_collector.translation',
            'data_collector.logger',
            'data_collector.ajax',
            'data_collector.twig'
        ];

        foreach($collectorsToRemove as $dataCollector) {

            if (!$container->hasDefinition($dataCollector)) {
                continue;
            }
            $definition = $container->getDefinition($dataCollector);

            $definition->clearTags();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
    if (!$container->hasDefinition('data_collector.form')) {
        return;
    }
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('data_collector.form');

    $definition->clearTags();

    $container->setDefinition('data_collector.form', $definition);
```

Comment: I did, no changes. But how could it? You "just" remove the tags, not setting a specific value.

Comment: Yes, that's because you filter for tag 'data_collector' and you have just removed that tag. The result should be that the element isn't shown in the symfony toolbar anymore.

Comment: Yeah, but that's good : ) Otherwise I couldn't overwrite the tags. The only question is why the overwrite does not seam to persist until the toolbar is loaded. And why it is when I do it via the `services.yml`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use your compiler pass to manipulate directly the service `Definition` of the service holding all these collectors ?

If I look at the [compiler pass responsible for loading the data collector](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2aeaa22e3171b5e1f10f2cc2a7ff7f6608b65f9d/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ProfilerPass.php), it seems that they are all injected using a method call injection.

You could use your compiler pass to rewrite the method call array using methods like `setMethodCalls`, `removeMethodCall`, ... of the `Definition` entity.

The method call manipulation documentation : [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html#method-calls)

Comment: The problem wasn't the way I manipulated the definition, but when the definition was run.